# Are all orthogonal projections conditional expectations?

Tags: probability, functional-analysis

When will orthogonal projections coincide with conditional expectations? Does that have something to do with the fact that not all closed subspace are probability spaces?

Is it why when we fix a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$ and consider an sub-$\sigma$-field $\mathcal{F} \subset \mathcal{A}$, then orthogonal projections are the same as conditional expectations? Otherwise, we have to require that the projection operator preserves the constant function 1 and is positive. Correct?

Comment: I think there is a little bit of terminology issues in your question. Given a sub-$\sigma$-field $\mathcal{F}$ of $\mathcal{A}$, conditional expectation with respect to $\mathcal{F}$ forms an orthogonal projection on the Hilbert space of random variables with finite variance, under the inner product $(X,Y)=E[XY]$. Its image consists of the $\mathcal{F}$-measurable random variables with finite variance. I think your question is asking: given an orthogonal projection *onto this image*, when can we assume that it is a conditional expectation?

Comment: (Cont.) There are plenty of orthogonal projections onto completely different images, which have no hope of being conditional expectations.

Comment: But I do think that any orthogonal projection *onto that image* is necessarily a conditional expectation. Try to prove it.

Comment: By the way, there is some loss with this perspective, caused by the fact that we're dealing with the finite variance case, while conditional expectation only requires finite mean. But cf. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1130804/approximation-of-conditional-expectation