# What does the conditional expectation look like when the $\sigma$-algebra is infinite

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Given a probability space $(\Omega,\cal F,\Bbb P)$, when $\sigma$-algebra $\cal F_0$$\subseteq \cal F$ is finite (which is generated by a finite partition $\Gamma \subseteq \cal F_0$), the conditional expectation $\Bbb{E}(X\mid\cal F)$ is a function that maps each set $A$ in $\Gamma$ to the mean value of $X$ on $A$, i.e. suppose $Y(\omega)=\Bbb{E}(X\mid\cal F)(\omega)$, then $Y(\omega) = \frac{1}{\Bbb P(A)}\int_A X \, d\Bbb P $ if $\omega \in A$.

So the conditional expectation for finite $\sigma$-algebra is quite intuitive, however, I have difficulty imagining conditional expectation for an infinite $\sigma$-algebra. What should the mapping look like? Is there any intuitive illustration for such conditional expectation?

Thank you!

Comment: Notice that $\Bbb{E}(X|\cal F)$ looks different from $\Bbb{E}(X\mid\cal F)$.  The latter is coded as \Bbb{E}(X\mid\cal F) and I changed the former to the latter. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conditional expectation $Y = E[X\mid\mathcal{F}]$ can be interpreted as the best $\mathcal{F}$-measurable approximation for $X$. More specifically: If $X$ is square-integrable, then the conditional expectation is the orthogonal projection of $X$ to the subspace of $L^2$ that consists of $\mathcal{F}$-measurable functions.

Note that the conditional expectation is actually a random variable.

Comment: Moreover, if $X$ isn't square integrable, then the conditional expectation can be given by a limit of such projections. Concretely, if $P$ is the conditional expectation restricted to $L^2$ and $Q_n(x)=\text{sign}(x) \min \{ n,|x| \}$, then we can extend $P$ to $L^1$ through the formula $\lim_{n \to \infty} P(Q_n(X))$. This converges in mean and also a.s. You could use some other analogue of $Q_n$, this is just a simple example. Giving credit where it is due: I learned this by asking http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1130804/approximation-of-conditional-expectation

Answer (score 4):

The concrete example I like to think of is where $\Omega = [0,1]^2$ with Lebesgue measure, and $\mathcal F_0 = \{A \times [0,1]: \text{$A$ is a Lebesgue measurable subset of $[0,1]$}\}$.  Then $ E(f\mid\mathcal F_0) = g $, where
$$ g(x,y) = \int_0^1 f(x,\eta) \, d\eta .$$
In fact, every conditional expectation can be thought of in this form.  I have a paper on this at http://ejp.ejpecp.org/article/view/37

Comment: 'The page cannot be found' :(

Comment: http://faculty.missouri.edu/~stephen/preprints/concrete.html